# How can I configure Filezilla to show the exact transfer queue's size instead of a lower bound?

Tags: filezilla

From time to time Filezilla shows a lower bound for the transfer queue's size instead of  the exact queue's size, e.g. `> 581.0 GB` as shown below:

[image]

How can I configure Filezilla to show the exact queue's size instead of a lower bound?

---

Full screenshot if needs be:

[image]